# Accessing a JSON array inside of a JSON object in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, arrays, api, object

I am testing my knowledge and ability with android studio and API's, I have been using volley and I have come across a little problem.

The API I have been using is the Ergast F1 API, this is the exact link I am using

https://ergast.com/api/f1/2019/drivers.json

I think my problem is that I am trying to access the array 'Drivers' but nothing seems to be working, I think this might be because it is inside the 'DriverTables' object, I may be completely wrong, like I say I am only learning.

This is my code here, any help is greatly appreciated

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView mTextViewResult;
private RequestQueue mQueue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
    Button buttonParse = findViewById(R.id.parse);

    mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    buttonParse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            jsonParse();
        }
    });

}

private void jsonParse() {

    String url = "https://ergast.com/api/f1/2019/drivers.json";
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
        response - > {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Drivers");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject driver = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String firstName = driver.getString("givenName");
                    String lastName = driver.getString("familyName");
                    String nationality = driver.getString("nationality");

                    mTextViewResult.append(firstName + ", " + lastName + ", " + nationality + "\n\n");


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        },
        error - > error.printStackTrace());

    mQueue.add(request);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Since your MRData is main JSONObject and you are trying to fetch "Drivers" child array from "DriverTable" object, you have to get "DriverTable" first from your JSON response.

MRData
-DriverTable
-Drivers

Try following Code:

```
JSONObject driverTable = response.getJSONObject("DriverTable");
JSONArray jsonArray = driverTable.getJSONArray("Drivers");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject driver = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String firstName = driver.getString("givenName");
    String lastName = driver.getString("familyName");
    String nationality = driver.getString("nationality");

    mTextViewResult.append(firstName + ", " + lastName + ", " + nationality + "\n\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.

```
try{
    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("DriverTable");
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject driverTable = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject driver = driverTable.getJSONObject("Drivers");
        String firstName = driver.getString("givenName");
        String lastName = driver.getString("familyName");
        String nationality = driver.getString("nationality");

        /// other codes
        }
}
```